# How to send vuejs array to another component without the array data being lost when i route to that component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, shopping-cart, persist

Hello I am currently building a vuejs shopping cart and for every product I click, I click I push that particular item into an array of objects called cart data as can be seen below

```
  methods: {

    addProduct: function(product){


          this.cartdata.push({
            id: product.id,
            name: product.name,
            price: product.price,
            description: product.description


          })


    }
  }
```

This code is where the buttons that trigger the addProduct function occur

```
 <div class="card-body" v-for="(products, index) in filteredProducts">
                <div class="card card-default" >


                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h2 style="padding:0px;">{{products.name}}   R{{products.price}}  </h2>

                      <p>{{products.description}}</p>
                      <button type="submit" v-on:click="addProduct (products)" class="btn btn-danger">
                          Add to cart
                      </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have another component called CartComponent and would like to send this array so that I can display it there with the data persisting when i route to the CartComponent. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is use the [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). You will store data in one store and you can reuse data across your components with ease.

Comment: And how would I do this in a way that is unique to each user? As I am using Laravel authentication. Or does Vuex handle different user session automatically?

Comment: Vuex can be different for each user. I have ecommerce solution in Vue & Laravel and I call API to get items for cart when page loads(it's based on session so basic laravel auth) and when user adds item to cart I dispatch action in vuex, send request to API and put data inside store and I have data same on FE and BE and also acessible across FE.

Answer (score 0):

I also wold recommend vuex for this, probably the best way to go. You can have a sessionID and save related information about the session in the vuex-store and then let your different components read the needed data for the specific session.

But if you for some reason really can't use vuex take a look at events, here is a simple [tutorial](https://medium.com/@jeffochoa/vue-basic-component-communication-using-an-event-dispatcher-be4823f006bf) how to make two components comunicate via events.

Answer (score 0):

With vuex, imagine that, before you do a router.push you set the array data to store, then array is "saved"...
when new component is created, mounted, etc. You can access your array from Store.
Vuex will hold your data while you move into router views.

Comment: Thanks. If i am currently going through vuex. Will the data still persist in the store if i refresh or login as a new user though?

Comment: to make store presistant after reload page you should to use `vuex-persistedstate` and if you need to update the store, then is necessary to set again the new info.